# Why is Sanji's Wanted Poster drawn?

Tags: one-piece

Unlike any other characters, only Sanji's poster are drawn.

[image: Sanji's poster]

In chapter 436, they ask the photographer, but there's no reply (or at least the answer didn't revealed after).

[image: Scene from Chapter 436]

Did he really forget to take off the lens cap?

How could he forget to take off the lens cap, if he managed to get another picture of the rest Luffy's crew?

Comment: for now, the only revealed reason is that the lens cap wasn't removed.
If there really is any other reason, then it'll be revealed in future.
But i personally don't feel there could be any other reason. Echiiro might have just made this for some funny moments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were to guess, I'd say that there were different photographers, and the one who was supposed to take Sanji's image made the mistake. Some bounty posters were taken during the raid on Enies Lobby (notice the posters of Sogeking, Robin and Franky).

[image: Straw Hat Pirates' bounty posters]

[image: Franky's bounty poster]

But Sanji was not there to begin with (busy closing the Gates of Justice), Nami was shocking everyone with her Perfect Clima Tact who got closed to her and Chopper was temporarily paralyzed on the ship. Hence only Sanji, Chopper and Nami were left for the bounty photos, Nami's photo was then taken by a magazine reporter (who may or may not be at the party, but can't go to Sanji or Chopper with that excuse), Chopper's photo was definitely taken at the party (notice his expression), however Sanji was busy with keeping up with the food demands during the massive party (can't have a cook's image on the bounty poster).

[image: party]

As for how nothing is mentioned. I would say he was nervous and made an honest mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Because when the photographer took the picture, the lense was still covering the camera and it came out blurry, so they used a substitute, which was duval's picture.

Comment: it wasn't blurry. it was black.

Comment: and also it's completely drawing, and not Duval's picture

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to the anime version in episode 389, the guy in the wanted poster is a real guy. The photographer thought Duval was Sanji.

[image]

Comment: The photographer did not think Duval was Sanji, it just so happened that a portrait of Sanji happened to be an exact match with Duval. It was unintentional and a complete coincidence.