# Where and when Mugiwara Crew's new bounty poster taken?

Tags: one-piece

After reading [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/why-is-sanjis-wanted-poster-drawn?rq=1) about why Sanji's bounty poster is drawn, not his real picture. I was just thinking about the bounty posters itself.
I know that aside from Luffy, the rest of the crew's bounty posters are taken after Ennies Lobby arc.

But how about their bounty hunters picture after time skip? 
I know it's probably when they are in dressrosa, but if I saw Sanji's and Chopper's posters, it's seems that their posters are taken in Sabaody Island.
And also Franky's bounty poster taken when he's in Punk Hazard or Fishman Island because it's shown his Franky Shogun, not his true face.
He only used Franky Shogun at Punk Hazard when battle with Buffallo and Baby 5 and when he's battle Fishman Pirate at Fishman Island.

So, I want to know where and when Mugiwara Crew's new bounty posters were taken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most other bounties in the series, I do not think that the location or the time at which the photo was clicked will ever be revealed in-universe, so here's what the new bounties make discernible:

Here is a picture of the bounties of the Straw Hats after time-skip for reference:

[image: Picture of the Straw Hat Pirate crew's bounty posters]

- **Luffy:** It's hard to make out when Luffy's photo was taken as it lacks distinctiveness, but as for where: It was taken on the Fishman Island. My basis for saying this is because he wore that outfit only on the Fishman Island. [This](http://www.renders-graphiques.fr/image/upload/normal/luffy-4.png) was his getup at Punk Hazard, whereas his getup at Dressrosa was [this](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/e/e6/Luffy_Disguise_Dressrosa.png/revision/latest?cb=20140220084810). As mentioned on the [Wikia article on Luffy](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy):

> During the Punk Hazard Arc, Luffy wore a long winter coat with red and white horizontal strips, along with yellow ear muffs, which he stole from one of Brownbeard's Centaur Patrol Unit.

> During the Dressrosa Arc, Luffy wore an open, short-sleeved shirt with a sunflower pattern, along with his standard blue shorts and yellow sash. He also wore a fake beard.

- **Zoro:** Based on Zoro's expressions, it is most likely taken just after his fight with Hyouzou on the Fishman Island. That's one of the only two scenes where he wears his bandana after time-skip (the other being in his fight against Pica), but the expression is strikingly similar to one he made after his fight against Hyouzou.
- **Usopp:** Usopp's photograph was taken at the moment when he was crowned God Usopp at Dressrosa with Hajrudin holding him up. The same expression can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/cULkgaBAb10?t=1m15s).
- **Nami:** Based on her pose, her photograph was likely snapped on the Fishman Island when she was with starfish Pappug, creator of the Criminal fashion line.
- **Sanji:** Based on his expression, his photograph is taken on the Fishman Island when he's running to jump in for a swim with the mermaids. The scene is from Episode 528 of the anime.
- **Robin:** It is hard to judge where and when the photograph was taken. All we can say for sure is that she's in her fighting pose, so it's either before or during a fight. A likely candidate for where though, is Fishman Island as that's where most of the photographs have been taken, at Gyoncorde Plaza as she gets ready to fight Hody's underlings.
- **Chopper:** It is most likely taken during a great banquet at the King's Palace as he has a cotton candy in his hand. Most likely, it is the banquet at the palace after the fight with Hody was over. This would put the location of the photograph as Fishman Island.
- **Franky:** He used Franky Shogun at Gyoncorde Plaza and at Punk Hazard. However, the former is more likely to be the location where this particular photograph was taken because that's where most of the photographs are taken, and I don't think there was anyone at Punk Hazard who could have taken this picture.
- **Brook:** It may be from one of his gigs as a Soul King before he continued his journey with the Straw Hats or from a scene during/after his fight with Hody's underlings at Fishman Island. However, as stated in Chapter 801 of the Manga, on [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRK1D.jpg), it is indeed his concert poster.

Comment: Well, because their new posters are shown after dressrosa arc, I thought their pics was taken at dressrosa. But just realise that they pics are from different location because Franky Shogun :D

Comment: Oh, about Brook's wanted poster, I think it's from his world tour poster. I think they said that when first time they see the poster.

Comment: @JTR Yeah, that's true. Checked the Manga and updated the post.